# .htaccess rule to rewrite calls from subdomain to amazonaws

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking to rewrite all calls to

```
subdomain.domain.com/video.mp4
```

to rewrite to

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/whatever/video.mp4
```

How would I do that?

And this is for embedded calls in video players/scripts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://s3.amazonaws.com/whatever/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dedicated folder for the subdomain, you would just need the following rule:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) https://s3.amazonaws.com/whatever/$1
```